# Unable to access Microsoft Office 365 on Ubuntu?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

My university uses Microsoft Office 365 to manage emails. The sever names are:

- SMTP: smtp.office365.com
- IMAP: outlook.office365.com

I had been using the email with Thunderbird on my Ubuntu machine, and it had worked fine for more than 1 year.

Suddenly, two weeks ago, Thunderbird couldn't connect to the email server. When I try to access the webmail using Firefox, it says:

> can't find the server at outlook.office365.com

I try with Chrome and the problem persists.

**However, when I switch to Windows (for the first time since I bought this machine), I can access the webmail using Internet Explorer.**

Since I do not know where the problem is, I have to switch to Windows just for emails. 
This is really really frustrating.

Would anybody give me a hint how to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you access the webmail using thunderbird under Windowz? Also what error occurs in Thunderbird, does `ping  outlook.office365.com` work? And do you have it set up as POP or IMAP?

Comment: @Wilf: thanks for you reply. ping doesn't work, it says `unknown host outlook.office365.com`. Thunderbird just says it failed to connect to server.

Comment: Can you connnect to it via a web broswer? It might be that it is blocke din some way by a proxy firewall etc

Comment: I have (almost) exactly the same problem (not on Ubuntu, though, but on Debian: I found this message while searching for solutions), also since a few days after months of normal usage. Neither smtp nor the web interface (via Iceweasel) work any longer ("can't find the server") from my home ISP (fastweb, Italy); the DNS however finds outlook.office365.com. The same machine (a notebook) has no such problems when plugged to the network of either my university (Udine) or of another nearby University (Trieste). I just discovered that the web interface can be reached using google-chrome, and that by

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Thanks for trying but changing the MTU wil not resolve the DNS problem that the OP is decribing.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling IPv6

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-cant-load-websites-other-browsers-can

set 'network.dns.disableIPv6' to 'true'

(Thunderbird: preferences: advanced: config editor)